# Flutter http 0.13.0 : String can not assign to Uri

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter2.0

I have upgraded http version and getting this type of error.

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Any solution for convert String to Uri?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per the changelog of [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog#0130-nullsafety0), you need to use Uri.

You can convert Uri using **[Uri.parse](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#uris)**

```
Uri.parse(your_url);
```